# Is it possible to send json data from java server to android client using TCP sockets

Tags: java, android, json, sockets, tcp

I want to develop a app, where user is automatically updated about new stories, just like facebook where it shows new stories at the top. One way for this is to keep timer and send request continously. But I want to send data from server to android client using TCP socket connection. I refered few links about how to establish a socket connection between two android devices. But they are sending just a plain text and server requires a response from the client, only then it sends the next data. But I want to continously send json data to the client. Is it possible to send json data continously from web server to android client, without getting response from client?

Comment: Use RSS for keeping your clients updated... Its is a simple XML format web service... More info here http://www.whatisrss.com/

Comment: @Aditya Singh, in order to get the data from RSS feed, I need to send requests. Is it possible to continously get the data from server, without sending the GET requests ?

Comment: If this is done while on mobile, it will keep the radio active 100% of the time; causing the battery to be drained quickly. This is not an advisable behavior for a mobile app.

Comment: @Nija, then how it's don in Facebook app. they automatically show the new feeds at the top..Is it done by sending requests again by keeping timer...is that the only way..?

Comment: Top of my head; I'd guess 'google cloud messaging'; but I've no actual idea. I've not looked into how FB apk does things.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [WebSocket](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455)? It's a bidirectional TCP connection through which you can send text and/or binary messages.

To use WebSocket, you have to use a web server that supports WebSocket ([Tyrus](https://tyrus.java.net/), [Jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/), ...) and a WebSocket client library on Android side ([nv-websocket-client](https://github.com/TakahikoKawasaki/nv-websocket-client), ...).